# Weird lines in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Suddenly these weird right angle lines started to appear in both headers and footers in MS Word.

Weird lines in Microsoft Word:

[image: weird lines in Microsoft Word]

Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

These are called "[Printers Crop Marks](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2011/02/09/what-are-crop-marks-and-why-would-you-want-to-print-them/)". They indicate the page margins, they are used by industrial printers to know where to slice the paper up to fit it in publications.

You can remove them by doing the following:

1. Click File
2. Click Options
3. In the pop-up, select Advanced
4. Scroll to the "Show Document Content" section
5. Untick the option called "Show crop marks"

[image]

Answer (score 27):

They're called crop marks

[image: Crop mark options]

To show or hide them just open *File > Options > Advanced* and click on "Show crop marks"

There are also [other formatting marks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-or-hide-formatting-marks-c2d8a607-5646-4165-8b08-bd68f9d172a0) in *File > Option > Display*

See also

- [Print crop marks in corners of a document](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Print-crop-marks-in-corners-of-a-document-8C04A7DF-F852-4283-9D39-444885458E06)
- [How to quickly show or hide crop marks in Word?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/943-word-show-hide-crop-marks.html)