# Keyboard shortcut for enabling margins' gridlines in Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013, margins

Weird lines appeared in my .docx documents, when I open them in Word 2013:

[image]

I know what [those are](https://superuser.com/q/1415053/156554) and [how to get rid of them](https://superuser.com/a/1415057/156554).

Here I am asking, how did I get them in the first place? Because I am *million percent* sure that I haven't visited [configuration windows or section](https://superuser.com/a/1415057/156554) neither in my Word 2010 nor Word 2013 for ages.

So, how it is possible that I see them now and haven't seen them yesterday or the day before yesterday? Is there some magic keyboard shortcut that I accidentally pressed that enabled them?

Comment: Perhaps your cat did it.    :-)    ⁠

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such shortcut key to enable/disable the option "Show crop marks" in Word. In addition, check if you have ever double-clicked on the white space between two pages to hide/unhide the the white space. If you hide white space, crop marks will turn to be linking marks between two pages.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I don't have a cat. But seems like a good hit! :> I have a chinchilla! :>

Comment: @HerbGu_MSFT I will have to go to another place where I left my computer with Word 2013, because it happened only there. But, your comment sounds like a jackpot hit, so I'd suggest turning it into an answer. I am more than sure that I haven't changed this option in configuration myself. And I am more than sure that I don't have a cat! :) But it is more than likely that I have double-clicked pages separator space or messed up something with display mode. It seems that your answer is pretty much valid.

Comment: @trejder OK. I'm glad to see that my reply was helpful to your question. I'm a single young man and  I don't have any cat but I love them very much. Cats' pink meat pads ~~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such shortcut key to enable/disable the option "Show crop marks" in Word.

In addition, check if you have ever double-clicked on the white space between two pages to hide/unhide the the white space. If you hide white space, crop marks will turn to be linking marks between two pages.

[image]